# What is the purpose of the .json file with version numbers that is included in chocolatey packages?

Tags: chocolatey

###### Background

I recently started taking the dive into making my own chocolatey packages.  I've looked through the [documentation](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/create-packages) as well as have looked at the [code](https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-packages) for the community packages.

In the community packages, there is a `.json` file included ([example](https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-packages/blob/master/automatic/7zip.install/7zip.install.json)) which contains some version information.  I've seen some that list stable/pre info:

```json
﻿{
    "stable":  "23.1",
    "pre":  "21.4-beta"
}
```

... and others that list truncated version numbers:

```json
{
  "7.3": "7.3.0-preview07",
  "7.2": "7.2.6",
  "7.1": "7.1.5",
  "7.0": "7.0.12"
}
```

When one types `choco new <pkgname>` to create a new package, such a `.json` file is not included in that default template.  According to the docs, all that is needed for a package is a `.nuspec` and a `chocolateyInstall.ps1` (`chocolateyUninstall.ps1` being recommended and `chocolateyBeforeModify.ps1`, `README`, etc. being optional).

###### Question

What is the precise purpose of this file/how is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of the packages that are maintained in the Chocolatey Community Chocolatey Packages Repository on GitHub use a system originally called AU, to keep the packages up to date.  One of the things that AU is able to able is the concept of multiple updated version ranges.  What I mean by that is a software product is pushing out new releases to multiple major versions.  In AU this is known as [Streams](https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-au?tab=readme-ov-file#streams) and the json file that you are referring to is where the latest version of each "stream" is persisted for the next time a check is made.

Unless you are actively using AU, and wanting to use Streams, you don't need to worry about this file.